# Birth year loop title JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops

I am creating a drop-down menu for birth year with a JavaScript loop.

```js
var year_list_start = 1938;
var year_list_end = 2008;
var year_options = "";
for (var y = year_list_start; y <= year_list_end; y++) {
  year_options += "<option name'" + y + "'>" + y + "</option>"
}
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = year_options;
```

```html
<select id="year" name="year" required></select>
```

It works like a charm, except I would like the to be completely different (text/title) and not selectable. Something like "Select your birth year". I tried this and that, but couldn't achieve success.

Comment: can you show us what you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: I tried added new var title = "Please select answer"; and tried adding it into the loop but then it would a. make all options unselectable b. would loop this var after every option c. screw entire loop basically...

Comment: This is not an answer, but the above should be `value='" + y`, not `name'" + y`. Per [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option), if the `value` attribute is omitted, the value will be pulled form the inner text of the option. In most cases this may be what you want, but it's best to get into the habit of doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set it as the initial value of `year_options` with `selected` and `disabled` attributes present:

```js
var year_list_start = 1938,
    year_list_end   = 2008,
    year_options    = '<option selected disabled>Select birth year:</option>';

for( var y = year_list_start; y <= year_list_end; y++ ) 
{
    year_options += "<option name'" + y + "'>" + y + "</option>"
}

document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = year_options;
```

```html
<select id="year" name="year" required></select>
```

Comment: Oh, I've tried something similar, but I was doing it totally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="year" name="year" required>
<option id="start" selected disabled>Select your birth year:</option>
</select>
```

JSFiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/Memorynotfound/13r1qfjb/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var year_list_start = 1938;
    var year_list_end = 2008;
    var year_options = "";
        for (var y = year_list_start; y <= year_list_end; y++) {
            year_options += "<option name'" + y + "'>" + y + "</option>"
        }
    document.getElementById("year").innerHTML += year_options;
```

```html
<select id="year" name="year" required>
<option id="start" selected disabled>Please select birth year...</option>
</select>
```

The `selected` option makes it so that it starts out selected, and the `disabled` option makes it so that you can't choose it as your answer.

Comment: @BenM I was in the middle of typing this when you posted.